# How to using regex to check if a string contains German characters in javascript?

Tags: regex

I am java web developer from China, now I met a problem to detect if the string contains special German characters **ßüöä** in javascript.

I am using `jquery.validate.js` to make the string only contains characters,numbers and underscore, my regex is `/^[a-zA-Z_]+\w*$/i`,now I want to change my regex so that it will allow the string contains the special German characters **ßüöä**, could anyone how to change the regex in order to archive my goal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z_ßüöä]+[ßüöä\w]*$/i` didn't work? Do you want to add just these characters or every letter from every language?

Comment: Your regex is [catastrophic](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). Omit that `+`.

Comment: Why only those? What about accented characters?

Comment: @flyFox what do you want this regex to do? your \w is equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9] do you want to match everything after there is a number? if so you should do something like: `/[a-zA-Z_]+\d\w*$` as I think that stops your regex being catastrophic. Though I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to change my regex so that it will allow the string contains the special German characters **ßüöä**

Simply include those characters in the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

```
/^[a-zßüÜöÖäÄ_][\wßüÜöÖäÄ]*$/i
```

This expression matches one letter (German included) or an undersocre, followed by any number of letters (German also included), digits or underscores.

Notice this does not include spaces or hyphens. Feel free to include them as well:

```
/^[a-zßüÜöÖäÄ_][-\wßüÜöÖäÄ ]*$/i
```

<kbd>[ideone demo](https://regex101.com/r/qV2eL6/1)</kbd>